# msbuild: "compile" context menu item for Custom Build Action in Visual Studio 2010 (on C++ project)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I've added a new build target to my C++ Visual Studio project (vcxproj).
This target runs a custom tool when the project is built. The tool processes specific files on the solution according to the ContentType and ItemType I specified.
This works well with project actions such as "Build" and "Clean".

Now I would like to support an action equivalent to "compile", i.e. right click on a file in the Solution Explorer and select to process this specific file with my custom tool (the same way "compile" runs "CL" for "C/C++ Code" file types).

I know I could add a Visual Studio macro to do this. This is not a good solution for me because it's harder to deploy for many users.
A better solution is to customize the vcxproj (or files imported by it).
I wonder if it's possible to add a "compile" like action in the menu (or change the "compile" behavior for file types other than "C/C++ Code") through msbuild targets scripts or PropertyPageSchema.

UPDATE: I've started [a discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/af6501ed-a02c-487f-9cd1-b4bee2af3904) on MSDN forum. Got some answers from a Microsoft moderator that helped clearing up some things, but the problem is still unsolved.

---

## UPDATE (2016), for VS2015

`AvailableItemName` seems to solve this on VS2015. For example, I have a custom target to process Excel files.

On the targets file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(SolutionDir)\ExcelOptions.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AvailableItemName Include="Excel">
      <Targets>ProcessExcel</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>
```

On the options file:

```
  <FileExtension Name=".xls"  ContentType="Excel"/>
  <ContentType   Name="Excel" DisplayName="Excel File" ItemType="Excel"/>
  <ItemType      Name="Excel" DisplayName="Excel File"/>
```

Now *Compile* is accessible on the Solution Explorer context menu after selecting an excel file, and CTRL-F7 works as well (for files that can be edited on VS, not for excel files)